# SP services Get list items data issue

Tags: spservices

i wanted to update fields in a form using sp services get list items,in that only few columns are being populated  in Xml response,even though the rest all fields have data ,it is not getting fetched,it was working fine earlier,but suddenly im facing this issue. pls help me out on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the missing fields in the CAMLViewFields parameter of GetListItems? The only time you can skip them is if they exist in the default view, otherwise you need to explicitly use CAMLViewFields. Someone may have changed the default view?

Structure of what you need in CAMLViewFields:

Example:

```
var viewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>";
                $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: "/sitename",
            listName: "List Name",
            CAMLQuery: query,
            CAMLViewFields: viewFields,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
```

...... etc....